# htaccess: change address bar to remove prohibit parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, wildcard-subdomain

I try to make subdomains with htaccess.
it's working fine so far. I'm using the subdomain as a Get-Parameter within another script.

However, if someone just uses this parameter, the subdomain-parameter is overwritten.

user1.domain.com/?site=user2 will display user2.domain.com.
(intern it is www.domain.com/index.php?site=user2)

So, I tried to make the site redirect from, ?site=user2 to user2.domain, but everytime I use the [R]-modifier the url is changed so you can see my local folders.
RewriteBase /path/to/basefolder didn't help there either.

Does anybody of you know how to change the addressbar, so that it is actually not /?site=user1 or /index.php?site=user1, but user1.domain.com ?
Or maybe what I did wrong?^^

Here is my current Code:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^\?]+)\?(.*?)&?site=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ http://%4.domain.com/%2?%3%5 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.php index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.*/
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?site=%1 [NC,QSA,L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this above your current rules (just below `Options +FollowSymlinks`):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^\?]*)\?(.*?)&?site=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ http://%4.domain.com/%2?%3%5 [L,R]
```

So when someone types into the URL address bar something like: `http://domain.com/some/path/to/file.php?foo=bar&site=user2&other=param`, they'll get redirected to (and the address bar changed to): `http://user2.domain.com/some/path/to/file.php?foo=bar&other=param`

Comment: Hi! thanks for your fast reply! However, when I type www.domain.com/index.php?site=user1 I am redirected to user1.domain.com/?site=user1. can I remove the last part, too? Also when I type user1.domain.com/?site=user2 it is still displayed user2.domain.com without anything happening within the url. I need either to be redirected to user2.domain or that ?site=user2 is ignored...

Comment: @Julian Something else is adding the `?site=` to your URL, the rule above specifically strips that out. When I put the rule in my htaccess file, `user1.domain.com/?site=user2` redirects me to `user2.domain.com/`, `www.domain.com/index.php?site=user1` redirects me to `user1.domain.com/index.php`. Even with your rules (which are all under the rule that I have) it works correctly.

Comment: well, I get the right site displayed, but the adressbar still stays the same. index.php isn't manipulating the adressbar and that above is my whole htaccess. there is a htaccess in a higher folder, but only with AddHandler php-stable .php and a few auth-commands. also a require user...  It's somehow strange that this text still appears...

Comment: @Julian can you post your htaccess file including the above redirect rule?

Comment: @Julian I see, there was a mistake when I pasted the code to here, the first `/([^\?]+)\?` needs to have the `+` replaced with `*`: `/([^\?]*)\?`. Also edited answer

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I tried something like that, too, but I seem to have changed something else, so this became an endless loop^^ now it is working fine.